# How to create new table element?

Tags: jquery, html

I create code but i don't know how (tr) add in table 2 times please give me suggestions ?

```
$(function() {

      $("#addProduct").click(function() {
         $("<table />")

     .append($("<tr /><td />"));         

     .appendTo("#someContainer");

    });
});
```

HTML

```
<button id="addProduct">Add Product</button>

<div id="someContainer"></div>
```

Comment: `.append($("<tr><td /></tr>"))`

Comment: [It works fine - you're just not filling any data into the table](http://jsfiddle.net/nQqRJ/). Are you sure that you're running the javascript in a `$(document).ready` callback?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You have closed the table row `tr` without adding data `td` to it.

It is created because you're not closing the `tr` properly.  table data `td` should be within table row`tr`

```
$("<table />").append($("<tr><td /></tr>")).appendTo("#someContainer");
```

Comment: Thanks It's relay help full

Comment: one more think if i want to add 5 column in a row and repeat rows  again so then what i do ?

Comment: I think this does the work (static approach)`$("<table />").append($("<tr><td /><td /><td /><td /><td /></tr>")).appendTo("#someContainer");`

Comment: It's work for me but now i cant add text please give me last suggestion ?

Comment: @user2424382 I'm not sure whether you're trying dynamic approach or ?? Check this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/WUEgS/), make your own and direct me to the link so that I can help you.

Answer (score 0):

This code should work:

```
$(function() {
    $("#addProduct").click(function() {
        $('#someContainer').append('<table><tr><td>Works</td></tr></table>');

    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

this code help you for better understanding

```
  $("#addProduct").click(function() {
         var item="<table><tr><td></td></tr><tr><td></td></tr></table>";
            $("#someContainer").append(item);  
});
```